# Crossplane Provider Upgrade issue: Only one reference can have Controller set to true. Found "true" in references for Provider/x and Provider/x

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, cicd, argocd, crossplane

We have a ArgoCD setup running in kind, where Crossplane is installed as ArgoCD `Application` (example repository here). Crossplane Providers are also installed via an ArgoCD `Application` like this:

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: provider-aws
  namespace: argocd
  labels:
    crossplane.jonashackt.io: crossplane
  finalizers:
    - resources-finalizer.argocd.argoproj.io
spec:
  project: default
  source:
    repoURL: https://github.com/jonashackt/crossplane-argocd
    targetRevision: HEAD
    path: upbound/provider-aws/provider
  destination:
    namespace: default
    server: https://kubernetes.default.svc
  syncPolicy:
    automated:
      prune: true    
    retry:
      limit: 5
      backoff:
        duration: 5s 
        factor: 2 
        maxDuration: 1m
```

The `Provider` is defined like this in the Argo `spec.source.path`:

```
apiVersion: pkg.crossplane.io/v1
kind: Provider
metadata:
  name: provider-aws-s3
spec:
  package: xpkg.upbound.io/upbound/provider-aws-ec2:v1.1.1
  packagePullPolicy: Always
  revisionActivationPolicy: Automatic
  revisionHistoryLimit: 1
```

Now as a new Crossplane provider version `provider-aws-ec2:v1.2.1` got released, we saw the following issue: The provider gets in the `Degraded` state:

[image]

And as an event we got the following error:

```
cannot apply package revision: cannot create object: ProviderRevision.pkg.crossplane.io "provider-aws-ec2-150095bdd614" is invalid: metadata.ownerReferences: Invalid value: []v1.OwnerReference{v1.OwnerReference{APIVersion:"pkg.crossplane.io/v1", Kind:"Provider", Name:"provider-aws-ec2", UID:"30bda236-6c12-412c-a647-b96368eff8b6", Controller:(*bool)(0xc02afeb38c), BlockOwnerDeletion:(*bool)(0xc02afeb38d)}, v1.OwnerReference{APIVersion:"pkg.crossplane.io/v1", Kind:"Provider", Name:"provider-aws-ec2", UID:"ee890f53-7590-4957-8f81-e92b931c4e8d", Controller:(*bool)(0xc02afeb38e), BlockOwnerDeletion:(*bool)(0xc02afeb38f)}}: Only one reference can have Controller set to true. Found "true" in references for Provider/provider-aws-ec2 and Provider/provider-aws-ec2
```

Looking into `kubectl get providerrevisions` we saw, that the new Provider got already installed (without us doing anything) and the 'old' Provider beeing not HEALTHY anymore:

```
kubectl get providerrevisions
NAME                                       HEALTHY   REVISION   IMAGE                                                STATE      DEP-FOUND   DEP-INSTALLED   AGE
provider-aws-ec2-3d66ea2d7903              Unknown   1          xpkg.upbound.io/upbound/provider-aws-ec2:v1.1.1      Active     1           1               5m31s
provider-aws-ec2-3d66ea2d7903              Unknown   1          xpkg.upbound.io/upbound/provider-aws-ec2:v1.2.1      Active     1           1               5m31s
upbound-provider-family-aws-7cc64a779806   True      1          xpkg.upbound.io/upbound/provider-family-aws:v1.2.1   Active                                 30m
```

What can we do to prevent the Provider Upgrades breaking our setup?

Comment: Note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions. This question is about upgrading pre-made software, that is not on-topic on Stack Overflow. You might consider to ask this on https://serverfault.com or https://devops.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: I noted you closing nearly all recent Crossplane questions. I really don't get it! I really tried, but there is exaclty 0 question about crossplane on ServerFault or other Stackexchange communities - nor is there a CI/CD tag (where there is a Collective for it here along other Cloud Communities). In this reasoning there should be closed any Docker, Kubernetes, CI/CD (GitHub, GitLab - also a Collective), AWS, Azure, GCP (all Communities!), Ansible, etc. etc. questions. Just looking at your Profile I can see top tag `kubernetes` - all of these should be closed also then using your reasoning.

Comment: This question is about upgrading pre-made software, that is not on-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: There is a term Site Reliability Engineer (SRE), which had been created after system administrators shifting from point and click to managing automated solutions: thus now having an emphasis on code - and in the Kubernetes world this is often working with the K8s API through manifests aka: editing YAML files. That's exactly what I describe in my question. What do you mean by 'upgrading pre-made software'? We all use pre-made frameworks these days, don't we? Should we start writing everything from scratch? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ArgoCD is doing the GitOps part in this setup, we need to let it take the lead in applying changes that have to be made in Git. With the current Provider setup, Crossplane automatically upgrades Providers without ArgoCD knowing anything about it. And thus trying to reconcile the state to what's stated in Git. Thus both mechanisms will get into an ongoing 'fight'.

To get ArgoCD into the lead of Provider upgrades through Git commits, we should configure the `packagePullPolicy` to `IfNotPresent` instead of `Always`, which means "Check for new packages every minute and download any matching package that isn’t in the cache" [as the docs state](https://docs.crossplane.io/master/concepts/packages/#configuration-package-pull-policy):

```
apiVersion: pkg.crossplane.io/v1
kind: Provider
metadata:
  name: provider-aws-s3
spec:
  package: xpkg.upbound.io/upbound/provider-aws-ec2:v1.1.1
  packagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  revisionActivationPolicy: Automatic
  revisionHistoryLimit: 1
```

BUT interestingly we need to leave the `revisionActivationPolicy` to `Automatic`! Since otherwise, the Provider will never get active and healty! I found [the docs aren't that clear on this point](https://docs.crossplane.io/master/concepts/packages/#revision-activation-policy) here.

**TLDR;** with `packagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent` Crossplane will not automatically pull new Provider versions and only a git commit with a Provider version change will trigger the download - and also the upgrade through revisionActivationPolicy: Automatic`.

Remember to be a bit patient for the upgrade to run through - it will take up to a few minutes and depends on what the Provider to upgrade has to do right now (we waited to short and thus thought this configuration is wrong, but it is not).